# Having problems while trying to implement a CheckBox in a custom todolist using a custom adapter?

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, android-listview

I am adding data through an editable text to a listview, listview is custom made and each row contains a textview and a checkbox, for now I want a toast message to appear whenever I click on a checkbox of each row for that I am implementing `View.OnClickListener` on the custom adapter and through the `OnClick` method setting the if else conditions so that my toast messages can appear but the problem here is while the listview is being populated the checkboxes are not working at all, I think the problem might be that the convertview might be inflating incorrectly or the checkbox might be working with the wrong view, can someone please help me on this?

```
public class todoFragment extends ListFragment{

private EditText mToDoField;
private Button mAdd;
UsersAdapter mAdapter;
private TextView todoTextView;
private CheckBox todoCheckBox;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getActivity().setTitle(R.string.todo_title);
}

public class UsersAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements View.OnClickListener{

    public Context context;
    public ArrayList<String> values;

    public UsersAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> values) {
        super(context, 0, values);

        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
    }

   @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        todoCheckBox.setOnClickListener(this);

        if (todoCheckBox.isChecked()){
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "CheckBox is clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "CheckBox is not clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.todo_list, parent, false);

        todoTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.todo_TextView);
        todoCheckBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.todo_CheckBox);

        todoTextView.setText(values.get(position));

        return convertView;
    }
}



@TargetApi(9) // remember this for isEmpty()
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_todo, container, false);

    ArrayList<String> todoList = new ArrayList<String>();
    mAdapter = new UsersAdapter(getActivity(), todoList);
    ListView listViewToDo = (ListView) v.findViewById (android.R.id.list);
    listViewToDo.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mToDoField = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.todo_editText);

    mAdd = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.add_button);
    mAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            String toDo = mToDoField.getText().toString().trim();

            if (toDo.isEmpty()){

            }

            mAdapter.add(toDo);

            mToDoField.setText("");
        }
    });

    return v;
}
```

Comment: Do the checkboxes look checked when you tap them ?

Comment: @JayeshElamgodil no nothing happens, an empty box and nothing happens when I click on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following two things should help you in making the checkboxes clickable

->> Add android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" in the parent ViewGroup of todo_list layout

->> Add android:clickable="true" in your todo_CheckBox view's definition

Once, you can start seeing the checkboxes clicking on the screen, as user370305 rightly mentioned checks on the checkboxes are detected with OnCheckedChangeListener and not OnCliclListener

Comment: I only Implemented android clickable true and OnCheckedChangeListener and it worked, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you to implement `setOnCheckedChangeListener` in `getView()` of Adapter class where you define CheckBox for ListRow.

Like, (May be code formatting error in below code)

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.todo_list, parent, false);

        todoTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.todo_TextView);
        todoCheckBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.todo_CheckBox);

        todoTextView.setText(values.get(position));

        todoCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked)                                                                                                      {
          Toast.makeText(getContext(), position+" CheckBox Status: "+isChecked, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
       }
     );     
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

And remove `public void onClick(View view)` from Adapter.